# Fixing a heated water dish: Pointers to a temperature table or guide for power resitors?

Tags: heat, insulation, waterproof

I'm fixing a heated water dish, used so that the dogs don't have to eat snow.  The previous dish was heated with a wire embedded in what appears to be ceramic, on a foil back on the bottom side of the dish.  This failed.  Previous experience with this company's dish (Farm Innovators) indicates that 1-2 years is a typical life span for this type of dish.

The rated power for this assembly was 60W.  It had a disk thermostat with about a 15 degree F hysterisis in series with the heating element.

It occurs to me that I could replace this heating foil with a handfull of 10 ohm, 10 W power resistors, connected in series, and glued to the bottom of the plastic bowl using thermal glue.

However, this puts the heat in a much smaller space.  It's not clear to me if this poses a fire hazard.  I'd like to find a guide that gives typical operating temperatures for a given geometry of resistor and surrounds.

In normal operation, the thermostat should be sufficient to protect the bowl and floor, however, I figure I need to design so that failure of the thermostat to open doesn't result in too high a temperature.

I would like to include a temperature sensitive fuse in the circuit.  Some that melts at, say 80 C -- well above the operating temperature, but low enough to not catch fire.

Alternate method: Use 32 guage nichrome wire (10 ohms/foot)  I would need 20 feet of this with 130v (rural power) to get approximately the same heating effect.  Invert bowl.  Glue roofing nails to bottom of basin.  Pour 1/8" plaster of paris or tile set mortar.  Allow to set.  Trim nails to 1/8 above mortar.  Wind wire from nail to nail in zigzag.  Place thermostat.  Add 2nd layer of bedding substance.

Nichrome reaction with highly basic mortar?

32 guage wire would puts a lot of heat flux through  small area.  Would the wire embedded like this overheat?

Comment: Figure out how much power their thing dissipates. Dissipate the same amount with resistors. No need for temperature calculations

Comment: Is it the heater that fails or the thermostat?

Comment: Ditto @PlasmaHH - If it were a 60W heater, get 10 pieces of some  identical resistor that will dissipate 60W in series, 10W rating each (ceramic.) Mix up some J-B Weld epoxy, and "glue" them to the bottom. I'd include a thermal fuse too, glued to a resistor. Be very careful to not expose any current-carrying circuitry in a manner that could shock the animals. (Think, inquisitive raccoon, chipmunks...)

Comment: @SpehroPefhany The zigzag wire embedded in foil has a crisp inch that has been reduced to powder.

Comment: the present setup uses several feet of element on about 1 cm spacing.  If I used 8 10ohm 10 watt resistors each each 1/2" x 2" then the total 60 watts is on a space of 5 sq inches.  While the average heat dissipated is similar, I could get local temps substantially higher.  Hence the request.

Comment: If operated from mai.s, don't forget about doggie safety. U

Comment: As Marla says. There have been a bunch of cases of dogs dying because of leakage from underground electrical vaults. Be careful for the dogs' sake.

Comment: Dry porch.  Plastic dish.  GFI outlet.

Comment: Main's isolation, High Voltage electrical shock, even a GFI will kill you if you are the load.

Comment: Consider a low-voltage transformer (like the 12V that path lights use), and instead of 20 feet of nichrome wire, you can do with two.  Silicone tubing around the wire, and plaster-of-paris to embed it, would work.

Comment: Interesting thought. But dropping the voltage by a factor of 10 would drop the current by a factor of 10 too (ignoring thermal effects) Power is R*I2 or V^2/R.  To get the same power I would need to use 1/5 of a foot. (20/100)  This is too short

Comment: Dave, you are correct, but there aren't many plausible accidents where you can get the correct current through the heart, without also grounding some of it.   Doing so without tripping the mains breaker is even harder.

Comment: Low voltage and nichrome wire is still workable; it needn't be 32 gage (that's about as small as is available).